# flow charts for languages

Tags: programming-languages, flowchart

I was looking at some syntax diagrams for SQLite and was wondering if they could be used to describe all languages (like Python, C++, etc.)?

http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html

From some CS classes I took years ago I remember groups of languages the could be described by DFA and what not, but don't remember many details and think this is probably different anyways.

Any clarity would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wouldn't usually call them "flow charts", but "syntax diagrams" (as you did) or "railroad diagrams". See the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_diagram) for details, and feel free to use my [Railroad Diagram Generator](http://railroad.my28msec.com/) for generating them from an EBNF grammar.

A DFA corresponds to regular grammars, whereas EBNF and syntax diagrams describe context free grammars. These are different levels of the Chomsky hierarchy, which is the basic framework for classifying formal grammars.